# Tab navigation in WPF grid view

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gridview

I have designed a wpf page. But I not able to set Proper Tab Navigation on it. Controls (Specialy gridview) on the page are not following tab index.
              In my Gridview,there is textbox ,and i want to set the tab navigation on it.Any idea....

Thank you.

Comment: Any idea, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabbing does behave strange in wpf due to the single tab scope of the ui-tree. You could perhaps try to set is IsTabStop property to ensure that wpf registers the tabstop.

Remember that for complex ui's with embeded layout elementsit might not be a bad idea to bind the tab-navigation to that of the container control.

have a look at this post: [WPF Tab Key Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547437/wpf-tab-key-navigation)
Rachel explains the problem quite elegantly.