# Changing next control on tab press

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, controls

I'm programming in `WPF(C#)`. I have a lot of controls in my Window. I normal situation, pressing `TAB button` causes to `move focus` from starting point(1) to next control (2) and then (3) and ... At the end of this scenario, I need to move focus from `end point(17)` to `start point(1)` as you see below:

[image]

How can I do it?
I need some thing like this method:

```
MoveFocus(Control controlName)
{
   // code...
}
```

Comment: are you creating forms?

Comment: No I use XAML for creating this window. **It is not WinForm**

Comment: do any of the controls have a property like TabIndex?

Comment: yes all of them have it. but as you I want to jump. for example I want to jump from control which has a `tab index = 17` to control which has `tab index = 1`

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8683962/66519?