# How does the KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex works in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose I have 10 controls in my page for 8 of which the KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex is not set at all. For the rest the tab index is set at follows:

```
control9:
KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex = 21;

control10:
KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex = 22;
```

So how the order of pressing tab key works here? The first 8 controls get the focus first then the control9 and 10? or it just depends where in the xaml file the controls have been defined?

PS. Please notice that I did not start the TabIndex from 1!

Thank you

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8648197/2470362) is the best explenation.