# Difference between Tab and Ctrl-Tab in WPF

Tags: wpf, listbox, focus

What is the difference between toggling the keyboard focus in a WPF application via Tab and via Ctrl-Tab? Which (dependency) properties and overridable functions and which control types determine this behaviour?

In my App, it seems that I can toggle between all focusable items via Ctrl-Tab, but only a few selected via Tab. How can I specify which items can be reached via which method?

Some items (`TextBox` or `Combobox`) are grouped in a `ListBox`. However, for some reason, the Tab key always puts the focus to some item outside the `ListBox`; I would prefer if it stays inside. Unfortunately, I cannot present actual xaml-code here as the view is dynamically created.

Comment: Check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547437/wpf-tab-key-navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547437/wpf-tab-key-navigation) and the [Keyboard.Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/focus-overview#Keyboard_Navigation) class to set tab order and how to set different tab controls for different items.

Comment: Thank you. The KeyboardNavigation class was helpful. The problem was, that the TabNavigation in the parent ListBox was wrong. Unfortunately, Snoop did not show me the responsible attached property.